# Different Result of stored procedure running from EXCEL or SQL-Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, time

I have a stored procedure which gives back different Results in EXCEL and SQL Server Management Studio.

The SP is the following and everybody can use it on each Table with a Timestamp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SelectByTime]
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

DECLARE @Datum_Start Datetime2(0) = Convert(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
DECLARE @Datum_End Datetime2(0) = Convert(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
DECLARE @WeekDay nchar(10)

SET @Datum_Start = DATEADD(Day, -1, @Datum_Start)
SET @Datum_Start = DATEADD(Hour, +6, @Datum_Start)
SET @Datum_End = DATEADD(Hour, +6, @Datum_End)
SET @WeekDay= DATENAME(dw, @Datum_Start)

SET @Datum_Start = 
CASE 
WHEN @WeekDay = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(Day, -2, @Datum_Start)
ELSE @Datum_Start
END

SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE timestamp > @Datum_Start AND timestamp < @Datum_End
order BY TABLE.timestamp desc

END
```

The Result in SQL Management Studio are correct. If i test the SP on an Monday, the Results are from last Friday 06:00 in the morning to actual day (Monday) 06:00 AM.

EXCEL shows only the Results form Sunday 06:00 AM to actual day (Monday). It seems that the CASE-Structure in the SP don't work when the Stored procedure will be executed from EXCEL.

What is wrong there? What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do not name stored procedure with `sp_` prefix. Has your Excel German  locale? I suspect that `@WeekDay = 'Sunday'` is the problem.

Comment: yes the EXCEL is german based on my local mashine.

Comment: Quick dirty workaround: `WHEN @WeekDay IN ('Sunday', 'Sonntag')`

Comment: thanks a lot. it works!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is the Language of EXCEL.

```
WHEN @WeekDay IN ('Sunday', 'Sonntag')
```

solves the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not name stored procedure with `sp_` prefix. It is bad habit and can collide with system procedure.

I suspect that your Excel use German locale during connection to SQL Server and SQL Server is set to English.
So when you do:

```
CASE 
    WHEN @WeekDay = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(Day, -2, @Datum_Start)
    ELSE @Datum_Start
END
```

I goes to `ELSE` part.

One quick (dirty) workaround is to use:

```
SET @Datum_Start = 
 CASE 
    WHEN @WeekDay IN('Sunday', 'Sonntag') THEN DATEADD(Day, -2, @Datum_Start)
    ELSE @Datum_Start
 END
```

Another is to set English locale before calling stored procedure:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;   -- British
```

Be aware that different languages can have first day of week (Sunday/Monay).